# Access VORA persisted view from HANA

Tags: hana, vora

I am trying to access VORA persistet VIEW from HANA through the spark controller. It seems that HANA is seeing only the tables from VORA and none of the SQL, Dimension or Cube View. Is this normal?

Views in VORA:

[image: Views in VORA]

HANA see only tables, no view:

[image: HANA see only tables, no view]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Spark Controller cannot access Vora views. It is planned to add this functionality in the future.